# Clear LSB of year and insert byte

Tags: c#

My program takes in a date time packet from a hardware device, which is of type byte. An example packet is:

```
byte[] packet = new byte[] {0x0C, 0x01, 0x15};

//packet[0] is the last two numbers of the year
```

As stated in the comments, packet[0] represents the last two numbers of the year. So, for example, this would translate to 2012 in decimal.

Now my question is, how do I return 2012 to the user? For the first two numbers of the year, "20", I know I can call:

```
int systemYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

Which returns: 0x000007dc, or 20'12' in decimal. I need no somehow remove the last two numbers from the year, in this case "12" and insert the packet[0] byte in that location instead.

I don't always want to assume we are in the year "20XX". If this program is run in the year 2101, this would cause problems.

Also, I can't always assume that the hardware will return the current year we are living in. This is what my program is actually going to check.

So, say for example packet[0] = 0x02. This would assume the hardware returned the year 2002.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: "If this program is run in the year 2101, this would cause problems." I can appreciate the long-term view, but there is no way this code will be running in 80+ years. Just prepend "20" and be happy.

Comment: LSB of `0x000007dc` is 0xDC (220), not 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int packetyear = year - year % 100 + packet[0];
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple as this. Forgot about the modolous operator. Thanks for your help and it worked peffectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last to *decimal* digits of the year with the modulo operator:

```
int systemYearLastTwoDigits = DateTime.Now.Year % 100;
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the Least Significant Byte of the year, which equals the last to *hexadecimal* digits of the year.